# (24,42): error TS2339: Property 'jwt_decode' does not exist on type 'Window'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm following this [angular2-authentication-sample](https://github.com/auth0-blog/angular2-authentication-sample) for authentication. I don't want the client side jwt_dcode and jwt_encode removed the both in the project. But still i get the error in this file `home.ts` `(24,42): error TS2339: Property 'jwt_decode' does not exist on type 'Window'.`

## home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

const styles = require('./home.css');
const template = require('./home.html');

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    directives: [ CORE_DIRECTIVES ],
    template: template,
    styles: [ styles ]
})

export class Home { }
```

Comment: which version are you using of angular2?

Comment: @micronyks I'm using the angular2 js. This is the package file https://github.com/auth0-blog/angular2-authentication-sample/blob/master/package.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and ended up using the [JwtHelper](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt#using-jwthelper-in-components) class.

Import:

```
import { AuthHttp, JwtHelper } from 'angular2-jwt';
```

Instantiate:

```
jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
```

Use:

```
constructor() {
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');

    // this.decodedJwt = this.jwt && window.jwt_decode(this.jwt);

    this.decodedJwt = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.token);
    this.jwtDate = this.jwtHelper.getTokenExpirationDate(this.token);
    this.jwtExpired = this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(this.token);
}
```

Comment: I don't want encode and decoding happen on client side. I don't want to use any helpers.